# Does the type Prop get special treatment by Lean?

Tags: lean

It may be a bit early for me to ask this question, perhaps. I haven't used Lean beyond The Natural Numbers Game (Which was a lot of fun).

I'm reading Theorem Proving in Lean 4. It says stuff like:

> Prop has some special features

and

> if p : Prop is any proposition, Lean's kernel treats any two elements t1 t2 : p as being definitionally equal, [...]. This is known as proof irrelevance.

---

#### The Question:

Does `Prop` get any special treatment in core? If not, how is proof irrelevance created? Is it just "naturally" a property of the bottom of the hierarchy of universes?

The related thing I've stumbled across is Propositional extensionality which has the following axiom:

```
axiom propext {a b : Prop} : (a ↔ b) → a = b
```

Is this the axiom that sort of creates proof irrelevance? Could I create a proof irrelevant analog to Prop with all the same properties/behaviors and start proving the same theorems again? (Not that I'd want to! of'c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Prop` has special treatment in the kernel. Any two proofs of a proposition are definitionally equal, and I guess this is just a built in feature, it's not "naturally" created.

`propext` is an axioms about equality of propositions. It doesn't create proof irrelevance. Note that `propext` deals with equalities of `Prop`s and proof irrelevance deals with equalities of proofs.

Something close to a proof irrelevant analog to `Prop` you could make is the type of `Type`s with at most one element. So you could define `Prop2 := { T : Type // ∀ x y : T, x = y }`. However, this would not satisfy proof irrelevance by definition, the equalities would be propositional equalities and not definitional equalities.